# Pass Parameters to DLL's Main Java

Tags: java, java-native-interface

How can I pass Parameters to Main via JNI?

Currently I load my DLL like:

```
class SharedLibrary {

    native void GetBuffer(ByteBuffer Buffer);;

    SharedLibrary(String[] exec_args) {
        String path = new File(exec_args[0]).getAbsolutePath();
        System.load(path);  //Load My DLL. I want to Pass this DLL some arguments.

        ByteBuffer Foo = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(.....);
        GetBuffer(Foo);
    }
}
```

How can I pass the DLL arguments? I need to pass multiple arguments.

Comment: You would pass arguments in when you run methods of the DLL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of loading a library into Java is to fulfill Java methods which are declared with the `native` attribute, such as `native void methodname(_arguments go here_);`. You can declare one or more native methods in a class, but all of them are expected to be defined (using JNI standards) in your DLL. From Java, you call them like any other method (by using whatever arguments are defined for the method).

If there are data elements you want the DLL's initialization entry point to receive, you need to make them static members (or methods) of some class and the DLL needs to know to access that class to get them. This, however, would be quite abnormal and is probably not the best way to perform whatever it is you're looking to do.

Comment: So the answer is essentially no? In other words I cannot pass Parameters to the DLL's main? I don't want to call methods. I can already do that as I call the GetBuffer Function. I want it to pass parameters upon loading and have the DLL initialize with those parameters.

I thought the purpose of JNI was to fulfill what's not there and what is needed :S

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: What the h3ll is a "DLL's main"? DLL's aren't stand alone programs, but rather are libraries with functions. If you're not going to be calling functions of the DLL why are even using it? This question isn't making much sense.

Comment: There is no concept of a DLL's main entry point. When Java loads the DLL, it will then call its JNI_OnLoad() function (if one exists) before returning to you, but if you examine that function's methods, you'll see that there isn't any room for arbitrary parameters of your choosing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you need "*multiple parameters*", any existing "*dll main*" won't work for you. You are most probably referring to [WinAPI `DllMain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and you probably think that this function is mandatory to any DLL, much the same way as every C executable is expected to have `main()` function. It is not. JNI in particular has [`JNI_OnLoad`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/invocation.html) which doesn't take any parameters, but so DllMain doesn't have any user-definable "*multiple parameters*" per your requirement. If you need your own parameters, why can't you create an initialization method? Even the `DllMain` doc is recommending that. `DllMain` is very limited in what it can do. Make the JNI init method static, so that you can call it before instantiating the `SharedLibrary` object in Java. What's the problem with it? Tell something about the "*multiple parameters*" you need so much.

Comment: Basically you know how you can run a program with arguments?

Example:  in the target line of the properties, you can specify launch parameters. Foo.exe  -SomeParam  -SomeParam2

I'm trying to do that :S

Comment: DLL is not a program which you run. It is a library which some program will load into memory and use functions from it. Libraries don't have any common entry point like program `main()`. There are only certain entry points by convention (like WinAPI DllMain) which work only in limited scenarios. But even those are not meant to passing arbitrary parameters.